# why am I getting List values instead of reference value, when i print ArrayList

Tags: java

```
ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<>();
arr.add(100);
arr.add(152);

System.out.println(arr);
```

I am getting result as `[100, 152]`.

Answer (score 4):

Because the `toString()` implementation of `ArrayList` (or a class in it's parent hierarchy) is overridden to display as such.

The class hierarchy of `ArrayList` is:

```
 java.lang.Object
    java.util.AbstractCollection<E>
        java.util.AbstractList<E>
            java.util.ArrayList<E>
```

If you were to inspect the source, you would find `AbstractCollection` has the following:

```
  public String toString() {
    Iterator var1 = this.iterator();
    if (!var1.hasNext()) {
      return "[]";
    } else {
      StringBuilder var2 = new StringBuilder();
      var2.append('[');

      while(true) {
        Object var3 = var1.next();
        var2.append(var3 == this ? "(this Collection)" : var3);
        if (!var1.hasNext()) {
          return var2.append(']').toString();
        }

        var2.append(',').append(' ');
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

According to java doc, arraylist inherited toString() from class `java.util.AbstractCollection`. Where, it override Object's default toString implementation.

`Full specification:`

Returns a string representation of this collection.

- The string representation consists of a list of the collection's elements in the order they are returned by its iterator, enclosed in square brackets ("[]").
- Adjacent elements are separated by the characters ", " (comma and space).
- Elements are converted to strings as by String.valueOf(Object).

Overrides:

- toString in class Object

Returns:

- a string representation of this collection